# Recommended SpamAssassin update channels?

Tags: spamassassin, update

I'm currently using SpamAssassin on a couple of mail servers that I look after. SpamAssassin runs in the context of amavisd-new on those servers and with the usual bunch of plugins (FuzzyOCR, DCC, pyzor, razor). Currently the servers are getting their rule updates from the default SpamAssassin update channel (updates.spamassassin.org). Overall the setup seems to be reasonably effective but some types of spam seem to wander right through it even though I've made repeated attempts at training spamassassin. My guesstimate is that about 85%-90% of the spam that gets through policyd-weight makes it through the filters and it's been getting a lot worse recently as spammers are getting better at working their way through filters.

Can someone recommend additional sources of filters to make SpamAssassin more effective? So far I've found [OpenProtect's update channel](http://saupdates.openprotect.com/) but are there others worth looking at?

Comment: Same question here too... It looks like there are not much fresh rules updates for spamassassin.

Answer (score 1):

See http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/SareChannels, especially the dostech channels.

Comment: **The SARE rules are broken to the point of being harmful. Do not use them. - This is written in big bold letters in the page:)**

Answer (score 1):

About the only resource that seems to stay current with SpamAssassin is spamtips. Check out their Ultimate Setup Guide - http://www.spamtips.org/p/ultimate-setup-guide.html

Specifically, the "Sought Rules" http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/SoughtRules is the channel I'm recommending.