# Spamassassin? update channels?

Tags: spam, spamassassin

I know this was asked [here:](https://serverfault.com/questions/110176/recommended-spamassassin-update-channels) but things seem to have changed.  It appears that the old SARE rules are [listed as broken](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/SareChannels)

The recommended SOUGHT channels seem to be down and DNS is broken for sought.rules.yerp.org

SO Is there a channel that does work? Or should I be looking for a spamassassin replacement?

For me, sa-update doesn't find any available mirrors..

Answer (score 1):

The SA Wiki has a section on [Updating](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/RuleUpdates) that's still relevant. The channel updates.spamassassin.org should work, provided your on a 3.x version (IIRC). If you're on an older version, time to upgrade.

I should mention that SpamAssassin is so well known that most spammers these days craft their spam to avoid it's rules. This makes it only marginally useful. The best way to combat spam is through a multi-layered approach, RBLs/SpamAssassin/Graylisting/SPF/DKIM/etc.

**Update:**
Running `sa-update -D` on my mail server fetched the Feb 25th update; I forgot to catch the output the first time, but this is what it looks like when I rerun:

```
Mar  8 19:08:59.093 [54937] dbg: channel: attempting channel updates.spamassassin.org
Mar  8 19:08:59.093 [54937] dbg: channel: update directory /var/db/spamassassin/3.003002/updates_spamassassin_org
Mar  8 19:08:59.093 [54937] dbg: channel: channel cf file /var/db/spamassassin/3.003002/updates_spamassassin_org.cf
Mar  8 19:08:59.093 [54937] dbg: channel: channel pre file /var/db/spamassassin/3.003002/updates_spamassassin_org.pre
Mar  8 19:08:59.093 [54937] dbg: channel: metadata version = 1293136
Mar  8 19:08:59.112 [54937] dbg: dns: 2.3.3.updates.spamassassin.org => 1293136, parsed as 1293136
Mar  8 19:08:59.112 [54937] dbg: channel: current version is 1293136, new version is 1293136, skipping channel
```

I'm running version 3.3.2_1, not sure what a 3.31 is. 
Sounds like your installation is borked, or your DNS isn't working right...

Comment: not sure about you, but I get a NXDOMAIN response from updates.spamassassin.org

Comment: I should add that I am using 3.31 version and am using RBLs/SPF/DKIM

Comment: See updated Answer.

Comment: Justin, you will get an NXDOMAIN from updates.spamassassin.org. What do you get from a TXT record lookup for 2.3.3.updates.spamassassin.org?